# How to build tow Angular apps but with the same design

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material

To make my project clean for future maintain I decided to break down the project into multiple apps, for example:

- Dashboard for Users who create post
- Dashboard for Users who just read the post

*It's just an example*

The Design in the multiple apps is going to be for sure the same, just with minimal changes like additional buttons etc.

I don't think that will be efficient if I did a change in the design and copy and past the code into another app.

I did research and I didn't find anything useful about it. Is there any efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular workspace mono repository and create builtin module and export to another angular apps

ng new my-workspace --create-application false

Then

cd my-workspace
ng generate application my-first-app